# User gets new group membership only after reboot (not after re-login)

Tags: debian, groups

I tried to add myself to the group `kvm` by executing the following command:

```
addgroup matthias kvm
```

I completely closed my session and logged in using gdm3 again. But still I don't seem to be part of this group:

```
matthias@atwork:~$ groups
matthias dialout plugdev users vboxusers adb docker
```

In constrast if I change to a text console (Ctrl-Alt-F2) and log in there I am in the kvm group:

```
matthias@atwork:~$ groups
matthias dialout plugdev users kvm vboxusers adb docker
```

I confirmed, that I had no existing session using the `who` command when being logged in as root. There was no session of 'matthias'. I only could solve the problem by completely rebooting the system. After the complete reboot I had the new group membership whatever way I used to log in.

This solved my problem, still I don't understand why I wasn't enough to just start a new session of the user.

(System is Debian sid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not, you need to log out and back in again in an X-Session. Or use `newgrp kvm`.

Edit: Just realised, you made a mistake, `addgroup` is the command to add a group, not the command to add a user to your group.

`adduser` is the right command to add a user to a group. So for you it is
`adduser matthias kvm` to add user "matthias" to group "kvm".

If you call `adduser` with one argument you create a user, with two arguments you add a user to an existing group.

Comment: Thanks for the newgrp command, I didn't know that. This works. But logging out and in doesn't. If I log out and in again I also loose the 'kvm' group membership I added with newgrp. So I guess this confirms that I started a new session.

Comment: Yes... but it's strange, logging out and back in again should also work. I just saw there is another issue I didn't see. The command to add a user to a group isn't `addgroup`, it's `adduser` :D
adduser adds a user if you use one argument, if you use two, the second argument is the group you want the user to be member of. In your case the right command would have been `adduser matthias kvm`

Comment: Thanks to point that out. Using both commands I get the same error (which seems to be correct now): The user 'matthias' is already a member of 'kvm'.

Comment: Yes, the error is correct of course, because you already did it. By the way, you might want to delete the group "matthias" you created accidently if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, but 'matthias' is my main group ID. I had that before and want to keep it.

Comment: You need to kill old X session completely and start a new X login session.

Comment: I had no X session anymore. I checked this using `who` and using `ps axu|grep matthias` and there was nothing. Still I didn't have the group after a re-login. But rebooting the complete server helped. Now I get the new group also on graphical login. Thank you all.